# jQuery bounce effect with border box-sizing and some padding

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, padding

If jQuery bounce effect is applied on a div with box-sizing: border-box and some padding, it shrinks by its padding size during effect animation. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnvx4bxe/).

### HTML

```
<div class="test">
    This is test div to bounce!
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.test {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #435ff3;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    $(this).effect('bounce', { distance : 10, times: 2 }, 'slow');
});
```

Can someone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug reported [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8867). According to the ticket this should be fixed in Version 1.12

A little workaround could be to add another container with the padding:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="container">
        This is test div to bounce!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Note: Both, margin and padding are overridden during the effect, because of the inline-style added via jQuery (in your case):

```
font-size: 100%; 
background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
border: medium none; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
position: relative; 
width: 250px; 
height: 140px; 
float: none;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eocycu10/)